# Matrix input and interpretation of the Input

Tags: c++

i have a short question about an initialization that I don't fully understand. 
About the code: I'm looking for pairs and my vector "vector  temp" saves the places where my loop found a pair. after my Temp is filled with some values I check it to look where the pairs were found. I made 2 for loops to loop through the vector. Outer loop i and inner loop j.  Temp stores the j value where a pair is found. 
Now about my question, this is the code

```
    bool repeat = 1;
    vector<double>::iterator rep_check;
    rep_check = find(repeat_check.begin(), repeat_check.end(), d_in[i]);
    if( rep_check == repeat_check.end() ) repeat = 0;
    repeat_check.push_back(d_in[i]);
    if(!repeat) out.push_back(temp);
    else out.push_back(vector<int> (1,temp[0]));
```

This part is still in the i loop!!!!! 
I dont understand the last part: 'vector (1,temp[0])'. this gets pushed into my output matrix (2x2 Matrix), but i dont understand the syntax here. How do i have to interpret this last part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing here is pushing back a `vector<int>` in a container (I guess it is a vector) named `out`. The constructor call is `vector<int> (1,temp[0])` and it says that you want to construct a `vector<int>` with size `1` and the vector elements (in this case only one) are initialized with the value of `temp[0]`.

The prototype of this vector constructor looks like:

```
explicit vector (size_type n, const value_type& val = value_type(),
                 const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

and the description is:
*Fill constructor: Constructs a container with n elements. Each element is a copy of val.*

Comment: To do we use a vector to push into "out" because "out" is a vector of vector and we want it to be stored in a new column? If that is right i fully understand the code.